# How rspec array should include? another array

Tags: arrays, testing, rspec

I'm trying to test if an array includes another (rspec 2.11.0)

```
test_arr = [1, 3]

describe [1, 3, 7] do
  it { should include(1,3) }
  it { should eval("include(#{test_arr.join(',')})")}
  #failing
  it { should include(test_arr) }
end
```

this is the result
    rspec spec/test.spec 
    ..F

```
Failures:

  1) 1 3 7 
     Failure/Error: it { should include(test_arr) }
       expected [1, 3, 7] to include [1, 3]
     # ./spec/test.spec:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00125 seconds
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/test.spec:7 # 1 3 7
```

The include rspec mehod no accepts an array argument, theres a better way to avoid "eval"?

- [Source](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/include.rb)
- [Spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Just use the [splat](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) (*) operator, which expands an array of elements into a list of arguments which can be passed to a method:

```
test_arr = [1, 3]

describe [1, 3, 7] do
  it { should include(*test_arr) }
end
```

Comment: OMG! This is mind-blowing...serious, this is really really useful in specs, I didn't know #include supported list of arguments. Thank you!

Comment: TIL about the splat operator.. and that it's not even required if the array is defined inline, in my case I did `it { should include(1, 3) }` (edit: which is exactly what the splat operator does.. )

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to assert the *order* of the subset array, you'll need to do a bit more than `should include(..)`, because RSpec's `include` matcher only asserts that each element shows up anywhere in the array, not that all the arguments show up in order.

I ended up using `each_cons` to verify that the sub-array is present in order, like this:

```ruby
describe [1, 3, 5, 7] do
  it 'includes [3,5] in order' do
    subject.each_cons(2).should include([3,5])
  end

  it 'does not include [3,1]' do
    subject.each_cons(2).should_not include([3,1])
  end
end
```

Comment: Honestly this is brilliant. Lets me check exactly what I need.